# Angular JS Encoded URL shows 404 Pag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

I have created AngularJS Application.

It's working fine with the URL below:

```
http://localhost/AngularDemo/about
```

If I modify the above URL like below it's taking me to a 404 page:

```
http://localhost/AngularDemo%2Fabout
```

I have done few changes in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^  index.html#! [L]
```

Comment: Why would you use escape encoding in your URL?

Comment: By some User Agents like Linked In , Indeed we get encoded URLs like above , so if i use that urls in application it takes us to 404 page . Above URL is a sample one

Answer (score 0):

This is default Apache behaviour. URL encoded slashes (ie. `%2F`) in the URL-path  will implicitly trigger a *system generated* 404. This is considered a "security feature".

If you *need* to explicitly allow encoded slashes in the URL then you can enable this in your server config:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

> By some User Agents like Linked In ...

However, this should not ordinarily be a problem. "User-agents" should not be encoding the URL in this way. `/AngularDemo%2Fabout` is potentially a different URL to `/AngularDemo/about`.

Answer (score 0):

I got resolved with following code.You can write in your app.js file

```
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```